# How to avoid entering keychain password

Tags: keychain

How to avoid entering keychain password, without disabling autologin?

Answer (score 2):

You can use insecure storage, but you really shouldn't do that, as it means someone could steal your computer and get your passwords, which totally defeats the point of using a secure keychain/password safe.

If your keychain password is the same as your login password, which is should be, and it seems like it is, then logging in will also unlock your keychain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 13.10 - open keychain application (named seahorse), click view and click the first option, which means sort or smth (sorry I`m using Russian distro and dont know exact names). You will see left column and a folder named "Login" -> right click -> change password -> enter user password -> leave the fields blank and press ok.
Thats all!